Trying to write a sane alternative to the visitor pattern, please help me review it
EDIT: This post has a single question but a lot of context. The single question is if there are downsides with the approach I'm taking over the common Visitor pattern.
I've been thinking about the way the Visitor pattern works and how to create a better implementation that is easier to understand and to include in projects.
I'm going to use the content from here as a reference: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor
This is the design they propose:

This is the client code that results from this design:
private Shape[] allShapes;

main(){
  exportVisitor = new XMLExportVisitor()
  foreach (shape in allShapes):
    shape.accept(exportVisitor)
  }

Ok, so here are the benefits of the visitor pattern, using that example:
Benefit 1
It let's the visitors process homogeneous objects by actually tapping into their implementation. In this case, the client passes the visitor to the Shape objects on the accept() method without knowing their concrete type. Then the concrete types tell the visitor "hey, this is my type, now you know my implementation" by calling something like visitor.visitCircle(this);. The visitor now has access to the implementation details of the circle. The client can now process a circle implementation even if it only knew it was a Shape initially.
Benefit 2
It is possible to swap the implementations of of the Visitor. I can swap the XML visitor for a Markdown visitor.
Benefit 3
I helps keep unrelated logic outside of the concrete classes. The shapes don't know anything about XML, Markdown or anything they don't need to know. Without the visitor pattern, it could be possible to do something like
interface Shape {
  getArea()
  getPerimeter()
  exportXML()
}

Then each shape could implement the way they are exported as XMLs. This contaminates the Shape interface and adds strange responsibility to the concrete classes. Why does a shape need to know how to be exported to XML, right? It doesn't.
Problems with the pattern

In order to implement the Visitor pattern you NEED to include the accept(v: Visitor) method in the interface of the abstract object and THEN implement that in all the concrete classes.

If the interfaces/classes weren't previously prepared to be visited, you need to modify them.

If you're trying to do this to a third party library, then you're forced to use an adapter on each concrete class and the interface. Like "VisitableShape", "VisitableDot", "VisitableCircle"... because you can't change their implementations.


Proposal
I think I found a way to get around the issues while still getting the benefits. I'll use the Strategy pattern for this.
interface ShapeProcessor {
  proccess(Shape s);
}

class XMLShapeProcessor implements ShapeProcessor {
  process(Shape s) {
    // yes, I'm using the dumb code.
    if(s instance of Circle) {
      // process shape as circle.
    }
    if(s instance of Dot) {
      // process shape as dot.
    }
    ...
    ...
    else {
      // fail with an exception, return null... whatever you want.
    }
  }
}

class Client {
 private Shape[] allShapes;
 main(){
  ShapeProcessor xml = new XMLShapeProcessor();
  foreach (shape in allShapes):
    xml.process(shape);
  }
}

With this approach I have the benefits of the Visitor pattern:

Process concrete classes behind interfaces but accessing their implementation.
Separating the operations from the concrete classes.

And I avoid the downsides:

Didn't contaminate my Shape interface with an accept() method.
Didn't contaminate my concrete shapes with knowledge about a visitor.
Don't have that confusing back and forth between the Visitor and the Concrete class.
I can apply this pattern to 3rd party code.
It's just so much easier to understand.

Are there downsides with the approach I'm trying to implement that the Visitor pattern doesn't have?

The premise of traditional design patterns is that you're trying to design an extensible component, e.g. designing a Shape class hierarchy. Then, it could be good to make it visitable. The situation is very different if you're trying to consume an existing Shape hierarchy and cannot modify it, then such instanceof checks are common. A key difference is the else fail part, this simply cannot happen when implementing a Visitor with all methods. Certain language features (like Rust enums or Java 17 switch + sealed classes) make instanceof checks safe, but also require design-time decisions.

You've just moved the double dispatch mechanism into a single, horrible, method. The difference is that now you can only get runtime failures when you forget to add a new visitable type to one visitor.

@amon I was under the impression that the idea of the Visitor pattern was to implement it on hierarchies that were already established once you realized you had to add unrelated operations inside their concrete classes. If the need for these unrelated operations is realized during design time, then it makes sense to do the double dispatch structurally.

@Useless So many languages rely on runtime errors. That's what testing is for. If you keep adding elements to your hierarchy but you're not creating tests for those elements, would you consider that a good software development practice? If you forget to test your code, that's a whole different issue. Even if the structure tells you to implement the method and you forget to add tests, the implementation could be wrong.

@AFP_555 people use compiler for a reason. Why suffer problems it brings just to reject the benefits?

@Basilevs I think the general practice would be to have tests. Not all languages are compiled. I was using a Java-like syntax there but this is a general software engineering question. I do see and accept the point of having runtime errors, but having tests is a given for me in any project.

It just occurred to me that the 1995 Design Patterns book (which popularized Visitors) pre-dates C++ support for RTTI (C++98). So back then, instanceof style checks were literally impossible, and the Visitor provides a useful workaround. However, the book cites prior art. One of these is from Smalltalk-80 (a dynamic language similar to Python), but that language makes it much more elegant to call methods than to use reflection+conditionals. A 1993 example of prior art in C++ is cited, which relied on a hand-rolled RTTI scheme with a non-extensible table, and doesn't even use C++ methods.

@amon: seen my comment below yours at Pete Kirkham's answer.

Downvoters, we are voting here for the quality of the question exclusively, even if you don't like the OP's idea, that is not what downvotes should be used for.

One point of the visitor pattern is to avoid the need of the repetition of code like this
process(Shape s) {
    if(s instanceof Circle) {
        visitCircle(s);
    }
    if(s instanceof Dot) {
        visitDot(s);
    }
    if(s instanceof CompoundShape)
    {
         // some code to process all inner shapes of s
    }
...
...
else {
  // fail with an exception
}

in each concrete visitor. Your solution fails this point, since the code above will be repeated inside XMLShapeProcessor, MarkdownShapeProcessor, FooShapeProcessor, BarShapeProcessor etc. over and over again.
There are surely cases where this kind of repetition is acceptable. When your object hierarchy provides some generic iterator mechanism to retrieve all objects from a graph (including all child objects), and the visitors themselve don't care for a very specific order in which the graph is traversed, and in case there are only a few concrete classes in the traversed graph, then the code section above will stay quite simple and not too large, hence chances are not too bad the repetition will not cause a huge maintenance headache.
However, it is quite easy to implement this generically, in a DRY fashion, still without an accept method. Just place process somwhere else (maybe in a Dispatcher class or a stand-alone function in C++), and make the visitor a parameter  of that function:
process(Shape s, Visitor v) {
    if(s instanceof Circle) {
        v.visitCircle(s);
    }
    if(s instanceof Dot) {
        v.visitDot(s);
    }
    ...
    ...
    else ...

That should do the trick. As Pete Kirkham correctly wrote, the C++ used in the GoF book was avoiding things like RTTI or direct type checks which were not standardized in 1995, hence this kind of solution was probably not on the agenda of the authors.
Final remark: you wrote your approach makes use of the Strategy pattern, pretending this would be the core difference to the original GoF Visitor. But in the original GoF Visitor, classes like XMLExportVisitor, MarkdownExportVisitor can be already be interpreted as different export strategies, just like an XMLExportProcessor or an MarkdownExportProcessor. So I don't think this is a useful distinction.

Seems strange that the goal is to DRY when every single concrete class has a boilerplate accept() method.

@AFP_555: that is boilerplate code provided once, independent from the number of different visitors. The virtual accept methods are implicitly doing the instanceof which your solution shows explicitly, nothing more, nothing less. But your solution requires the repetiion of the instanceof ceremony in each concrete visitor, whilst the accept mechanism does this generically once.

@AFP_555 To be fair, classes with a single method are an implementation detail of a language that doesn't support higher-order functions or standalone function definitions.

@chepner: where have you found classes with a single method in the Visitor pattern, or this specific example?

@DocBrown I misinterpreted OP's first comment here about concrete classes having only an accept method, rather than multiple methods. But the point stands that in a language that doesn't support higher-order languages or standalone functions, you'd have to replace a regular function like accept with an instance of a class that provides an accept method.

@chepner: has this anything to do with the OP's question or my answer?

I'm assuming (perhaps incorrectly), that the boilerplate OP is referring to is the extra classes to be defined; I'm just saying that's due to the language being used, not the Visitor pattern itself.

@chepner: the OP's comment was about the extra accept method which has to be introduced into, let's say, the Shape hierarchy, to make the original Vistor pattern work. It requires typically a one-liner implementation in each concrete Shape to call the correct visit method.  The OP's approach avoids this (for the price of creating more boilerplate code at a different place).

@DocBrown I'm not trying to avoid boilerplate code, I'm trying to create a pattern that is easier to understand for a team with a wide spectrum of seniority.

@AFP_555: as you might have noted, I am not "judging" your solution - it will surely work and does not require to add an accept method to the hierarchy, as you stated by yourself. It is also less DRY than the original Visitor. For some situations, that's ok, for some it may not. Context is king.

@DocBrown Yeah, I agree. I guess it's hard guess the tone of people over messages, but I'm actually enjoying that this is generating conversation. I do agree that context is very important to know when a pattern is good or not, and it is lacking in here. I've found myself confused by the visitor pattern in the wild and I've seen other people struggle with it, so I thought I could tackle the biggest issue it has (at least in my experience)... being confusing.

@AFP_555: note I added a suggestion how to implement your idea in a DRY fashion.


Are there downsides with the approach I'm trying to implement that the Visitor pattern doesn't have?


It values visiting hierarchies which are not designed up-front to be visitable, which was never a particular goal of the visitor pattern
It values simplifying the visitee over complicating the visitor
(equivalently) it values ease of adding visitee types over ease of adding new visitor types
It can fail (or silently misbehave) if the visited hierarchy has non-final intermediate types which may be used for real objects. At least, it's brittle because you need to carefully test the types in the correct order (reverse topological sort), and this needs to be manually maintained in every visitor

All of these may be valid choices for a particular scenario, but IMO you're exaggerating how widely applicable they are.


Didn't contaminate my Shape interface with an accept() method.
Didn't contaminate my concrete shapes with knowledge about a visitor.



...

I can apply this pattern to 3rd party code.


These all say the same thing: that you want to detach the mechanism for visiting some hierarchy, from the hierarchy itself.
Fortunately there are other ways to do this that don't require writing a sequence of instanceof tests by hand, in every visitor.
Taking a step back, the general problem we're addressing is called "double dispatch". Single dispatch is where the concrete method actually called depends on the (single) dynamic type of the object it's called on. Double dispatch is where the concrete method actually called depends on two types (here, the visitee and the visitor).
A better solution than your original would be a standalone double-dispatcher: it has the same brittleness I described above (point 4), but at least only has to be written once.
One is version is the straight translation already posted by Doc Brown:
  visit(Shape s, ShapeVisitor v) {
    if(s instance of Circle) {
      v.visitCircle(asCircle(s));
    }
    if(s instance of Dot) {
      v.visitDot(asDot(s));
    }
    ...
    ...
    else {
      // fail with an exception, return null... whatever you want.
    }
  }

Another, depending on language, is the more data-driven style:
class DD {
map<pair<typeid,typeid>, method> map_;

public:
  dispatch(auto& visitee, auto& visitor)
  {
    pair key{typeof(visitor),
             typeof(visitee)};
    map_[key](visitee, visitor);
    // with handling for missing keys
  }
};

This is more work to set up, but can work as glue layer when neither hierarchy was designed for visitation.


Totally agree. It really seems the objective of this pattern was to be established during initial design time.  2. The visitor doesn't seem complicated to me. I just switched from having 5 methods in the visitor to having 1 method with conditionals. 3. Again, the visitor has 1 method instead of a method per visitee. 4. Yes, the runtime error is a problem, but a minimal suite of tests would catch that. But I do agree, it is 100% a downside.  Thanks for this analysis, it's great!


Something else about complexity is that I was actually trying to tackle exactly that with this proposal. The back and forth between the visitor and the visitees is so confusing to a lot of people that they just don't grasp the actual purpose of the pattern. With the proposal I created it would be easy to get it. In a real project with junior devs I wouldn't use the visitor. I remember the first time I saw it in the wild I was just baffled by that back and forth, I thought it was a mistake. It took so long for me to grasp its purpose. I created this question partly for education purposes.

Have you tried just showing these junior devs the GoF description of the pattern? Spending effort so they don't have to learn something they're likely to come across later anyway, and that isn't so complicated, is doing them a very questionable favour.

The Visitor pattern as presented in 'Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software' is one of the patterns which are there to overcome a limitation in the implementation language.
The GoF book was published in 1994 before RTTI was added to C++ *, so there was no equivalent of instanceof available to use for the visitor pattern, or better multiple dispatch mechanisms as are available in Lisps or more modern languages **.
So, yes, now you can use run time type information in languages that have it to do multiple dispatch, and you might lose some static type checking and performance by doing that, depending on language. Whether it is better or not rather depends on the language rather than something general, since the pattern is only there in that form for languages which don't have something better already. You would not use the pattern in Lisp as you already have multi-dispatch methods.
* or at least it was written before it was commonly implemented in compilers, I'm not 100% sure of the timeline
** more modern than 1994 in case people again start pointing out that Python isn't that modern.

I think this is the answer. The GoF book uses very ancient C++, not even templates, and many peculiarities have to be ascribed to this. The book does also use Smalltalk examples, which is dynamic and Python-like. Instanceof checks were possible ((s inheritsFrom: Circle) ifTrue: [...]) But its syntax made it much more convenient to add methods than to use lots of conditionals, there isn't a nice else if construct. The book explicitly acknowledges Lisp/CLOS multi-dispatch and presents Visitor as a way to implement this in single-dispatch languages.

This is most probably correct. My 1992 edition of Stroustrup's C++ book, contains a chapter about RTTI - but starts wit a remark there were no RTTI standard at  that time beyond virtual methods (just checked it). So this was all in flow at that time. Adding an accept method to all classes of a hierarchy is probably the straightforward alternative here, but, as the OP stated correctly, it can be problematic when the code of the hierarchy cannot be modified.

I've never liked the Visitor pattern, and I think it rightfully gets a lot of hate.  It creates a tangled mess of coupling. Every new shape requires a new implementation in both your vistor interface and every concreate visitor class.
In addition, what's odd to me about the example that you link to is that the GoF Builder pattern (not to be confused with Josh Bloch's pattern of the same name) seems more appropriate for the problem at hand.  I find it to be a 'saner' approach in general, and it can be adapted fairly easily.  It avoids the bi-directional coupling inherent in visitor.
That said, discussing patterns with such abstract examples isn't very useful, in my experience.  The details of a specific problem to be solved are necessary to truly judge a design approach (patterns or otherwise) for appropriateness.
The major downside of the approach you describe is that you retain the main disadvantages of the visitor: every new class of object you want to handle requires a new 'implementation' in your processor method.  I used to be strongly in the camp that using the type of objects like this was a problem in itself.  I've softened on that but it's not something I would use over a large set of types, and/or if the set of types is expected to grow over time.

The Visitor pattern was always aiming for very stable object hierarchies. However, it is easy to come around the limitation that each new Shape requires a new implementation for each visitor, at least technically. When adding a new Shape and extending the Visitor interface for this Shape, one can provide a default implementation for the visitMyNewShape method, for example an empty method. It depends heavily on the context whether that's a good idea, or not, of course.
